# What are some prediction methods when you have missing covariate information?

Tags: missing-data

Say, you have the following information for training and test data:

Response: $y$

Covariates: $X = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_p)$

However, you know that your covariates, $X$, are not enough to predict $y$ well. You know for sure that there are other covariates, $Z = (z_1, z_2, ..., z_m)$, that including would predict $y$ better. But you just can't get the information for $Z$.

What prediction methods are good for this scenario?

The only method I've come across is [Prediction with Missing Data via Bayesian Additive Regression Trees](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.0618.pdf). I'm looking for more methods since this didn't work that much better than linear regression and random forest for my data. Also, it did not include any missing data.

Comment: It's not totally clear to me from your description but I guess we can assume you have partial information on the Z's?

Comment: No partial information. Just the knowledge that you don't have enough information to predict.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: if you have too few covariates to predict $y$ well, you need to gather more information.

The problem you are facing is [*Omitted-variables bias*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias). A question (and useful answers) about which variables to include can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/188557/112892). The paper you linked is about missing values *within* a covariate, but not entirely missing covariates.