# How does non-collapsibility and the lack of an error term affect coefficients in regression

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, error, bias, regression-strategies

I have read from [here](https://www.fharrell.com/post/robcov/) that in nonlinear models such as the logit and Cox, *because of a lack of an error term*, coefficients may be biased (typically towards zero) when covariates are omitted; I see how bias may arise if excluded covariates are confounders, but the article implies bias as an implication regardless; I do not understand why this is the case. For example, in linear regression, the error term just quantifies the distance from the observed data to the fitted line; additional coefficients, unless they are confounders, reduce the error but do not change the values of the coefficients. I don't see how it is 'absorbing' any lack of fit?

I can see how, from [here](https://www.fharrell.com/post/marg/), non-collapsibility can lead to an OR that is not representative (biased?), and that is clear: I assume this extends to the logit model. Further, I am aware that risk ratios are collapsible, so they do not have this issue; however, these can be estimated from nonlinear models that don't have error terms. This adds to my confusion around what relationship between nonlinearity, error terms and bias.

Comment: It might be better to let Frank Harrell clarify that.  I think it may be an infelicitous phrasing.  It is the non-collapsibility that does this.  Note that econometricians conceptualize logistic regression as having a logistically-distributed error term that is thresholded.  That isn't the way I prefer to think about it, but it isn't mathematically incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

"Lack of an error term" needs clarification. You can, of course, set up probability models for GLMs like logistic regression to have some bizarre error terms. This belabors the point though because these terms are not closed under mixtures as normal errors are. Additionally, Poisson GLMs which use the log link are *collapsible* and so, despite not having an error term, omitting variables in Poisson models only reduces efficiency as was the case for normal data, but causes no bias per se.

*Omitted variable bias* requires non-collapsibility of the link function.
This causes a kind of "prediction at the mean" bias for the unobserved strata of variables. Only for collapsible link is this prediction at the mean unbiased. But in all other cases, there is bias. For logistic regression and Cox models, each curve represents a stratum of an unmeasured variable. For generalized linear mixed models, each curve represents an individual-level dose/response curve.

[Omitted variable bias: which predictors do I need to include, and why?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188557/omitted-variable-bias-which-predictors-do-i-need-to-include-and-why/312898#312898)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I didn't see anything about dependent observations in the two links? I'm a bit concerned that the link is incorrect; the first should lead to a post is titled 'Incorrect Covariate Adjustment May Be More Correct than Adjusted Marginal Estimates', is this what you're seeing?

Comment: @geoff mixed models or mixed effects models usually imply the presence of dependent data.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't see anything about mixed models in either link? Could you confirm the title of the blog post you're viewing? I wasn't intending for my question to be about mixed models and errors on different levels. The link should lead to a blog post where the point is made about a single level model and adjusting for covariates in this.

Comment: @Geoff hmm you're right I misread, I edited the question to focus on what I think your question is.