# Crude multivariate binomial regression OR vs univariate binomial regression OR?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, multiple-regression, odds-ratio

I've performed an univariate binomial regression with OR (95% CI) and I obtain this result:

```r
> full.model <- glm(Re_OUT ~ t0_FIO1 , data = db,family=binomial())
> logistic.display(full.model)

Logistic regression predicting Re_OUT : 1 vs 0 
 
                     OR(95%CI)         P(Wald's test) P(LR-test)
t0_FIO1 (cont. var.) 1.03 (1.03,1.04)  < 0.001        < 0.001   
                                                                
Log-likelihood = -212.7811
No. of observations = 383
AIC value = 429.5621
```

Then I performed a multivariate binomial regression.
I should find that the t0_FI01 has a crude OR equal to the OR of the univariate binomial regression, but this isn't so.

```r
> full.model <- glm(Re_OUT ~ t0_FIO1 +  t0_IOT  , data = db, 
                    family=binomial())
> logistic.display(full.model)

Logistic regression predicting Re_OUT : 1 vs 0 
 
                     crude OR(95%CI)      adj. OR(95%CI)       P(Wald's test) P(LR-test)
t0_FIO1 (cont. var.) 1.03 (1.03,1.04)     1.03 (1.02,1.03)     < 0.001        < 0.001   
                                                                                        
t0_IOT: 1 vs 0       63.06 (15.17,262.1)  27.86 (6.53,118.82)  < 0.001        < 0.001   
                                                                                        
Log-likelihood = -189.8483
No. of observations = 383
AIC value = 385.6967
```

Why?

Comment: Logistic regression coefficients are not collapsible. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/637668/how-does-non-collapsibility-and-the-lack-of-an-error-term-affect-coefficients-in) and especially also the links therein for more details.