# Should difference between accuracy of model on training data and testing data be considered for model selection?

Tags: machine-learning, model-selection, validation

Suppose I have two models (Model 1 and Model 2), Where

1. Accuracy of Model 1 on test data is higher than that in Model 2
2. Difference between accuracy of model on test data and training data is higher Model 1 and Model 2

Which is the better model? Why?

For example, Model 1 is 95% accuracy on test set and 98% accurate on training set, while Model 2 92% accurate on both test and training set.